# postgresql libpqxx - no result after transaction

Tags: postgresql, transactions, libpqxx

These is my code:

```
std::unique_ptr<pqxx::connection> conn = connect();

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> conv;

try{
    conn->prepare("add_pr_file", "select * from add_pr_file($1, $2, $3)");
    conn->prepare("entire_add_pr", " select * from entire_add_pr($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)");

    pqxx::work tr(*conn.get(), "add_pr");

    pqxx::binarystring data((pr.input_data.empty() ? nullptr : (const void *)pr.input_data.data()), pr.input_data.size());

    tr.prepared("entire_add_pr")(pr.guid.to_str())(conv.to_bytes(pr.name))(data)(std::to_string(pr.rate))(conv.to_bytes(pr.type));

    for (auto file : pr.files) {
        tr.prepared("add_pr_file")(pr.guid.to_str())(conv.to_bytes(file.path))(type_cnv::type(file.module)).exec();
    }

    tr.commit();

}
catch (const pqxx::pqxx_exception &exc) {
    THROW(exc.base().what()); 
}
```

I couldn't execute `entire_add_pr` function. This function must add one row in table `pr`. No exeptions are occured, but at the result of commit there are no rows in `pr` table. However `add_pr_file` statement gets result after commit.
These is `entire_add_pr` function:

```
create or replace function entire_add_pr( _guid uuid, _name character varying, _input_data bytea, _rate integer, _type_name character varying )
returns void as $$
begin       
   insert into pr (guid, name, input_data, rate_priority, pr_type_id) values (_guid, _name, _input_data, _rate, (select id from pr_type where type_name = _type_name)); 
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

The function works well if I execute the query from postgresql command line:

```
select * from entire_add_pr('1aaa9aaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaa111', 'pr_name', '123', 10, 'test type');
```

Comment: In I place the error in function `entire_add_pr`, for example add string `raise notice '%', unknown_var`, code will be executed without exceptions too, so I come to conclusion that plpgsql function wasn't executed at all.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to execute `exec` method:

```
tr.prepared("entire_add_pr")(pr.guid.to_str())(conv.to_bytes(pr.name))(data)(std::to_string(pr.rate))(conv.to_bytes(pr.type)).exec();
```